# Bot Framework - Web Chat - Always show sendbox

Tags: botframework, web-chat

I am using the web chat control provided by Microsoft.  [Webchat Control GitHub](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat)

Is there a way to make the send box always visible?  Right now when I scroll the the transcript it also scrolls the send box out of view.

I notice that on the [Health Bot](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/project/health-bot/) they seem to have this functionality but I can't determine the options they are using or if they are using the basic webchat.

[image: Health Bot With Scroll Bar Above Send Box]

I believe that the only way to customize this control is using the [Style Options](https://bisser.io/bot-framework-v4-webchat-styling-options/) but I don't see anything for changing how the scroll bar works in relation to the send box.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Can you please elaborate on what you mean about the sendbox being visible? I checked the healthbot, and the send box is static and is always visible, even when scrolling

Comment: is your issue resolved?